# What software is in the Canonical Partners repository?

Tags: repository, canonical, ubuntu-wiki

I'd please like to know what software (or see the list) is in that repository.
I enabled it and of course let the system update the package list.. but I can't seem to find both Chrome nor Skype after it (using Ubuntu Software).

Any idea???
Shouldn't it be in a wiki or the official documentation?
Thanks :)

Comment: No Chrome & Skype are not there, Google & Microsoft don't allow it.  Minor doco is available in certain places (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html) but you can always use a browser to just look, for example http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/ shows those starting with A  (*lists need maintenance, no-one has stepped up to do it as the work is at the whim of the partner companies*)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ grep Package /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_partner_binary-amd64_Packages
Package: adobe-flashplugin
Package: adobe-flash-properties-gtk
Package: adobe-flash-properties-kde
Package: google-cloud-sdk
```

How to install Skype is mentioned in [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html). How to install Google Chrome is not, but OTOH it's [not very hard to find out](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how up-to-date this is but you can use two commands:

```
$ wget --spider -r --no-parent http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/
    (...SNIP...)
Found no broken links.

FINISHED --2018-05-20 20:01:58--
Total wall clock time: 1m 35s
Downloaded: 507 files, 1.2M in 0.4s (3.24 MB/s)

$ ls -l archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/
total 68
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:00 a
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:00 c
drwxrwxr-x  6 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:00 d
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:00 e
drwxrwxr-x  9 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 g
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 h
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 i
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 k
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 m
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 n
drwxrwxr-x  5 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 o
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 p
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 s
drwxrwxr-x 14 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 t
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 u
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 v
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 May 20 20:01 x
```

Now you have a complete index (I hope) of all packages available on your drive. To check out what's available in the `a` category:

```
$ ls archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a
acroread  adobe-flashplugin
```

The size of the list is nominal so you might want to keep it on your drive or delete it:

```
$ du -h -d1 archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/
32K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/g
12K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/e
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/n
12K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/x
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/v
12K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/c
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/p
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/i
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/s
12K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a
52K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/t
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/k
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/u
8.0K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/h
16K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/o
20K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/d
12K     archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/m
248K    archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/
```

Comment: To then list available packages: `ls -1 ./archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/* | awk 'NF && !/:/{print}'`